# Programming on Lift on Realtime - Is it possible?

Tags: scala, real-time, lift

I have been programming Rails and Lift for a while.
Rails, said, a joy to work on.
But Lift performance is too awesome to be ignored.
However, I find building stuff inside Lift is way slower compare to rails. For example, whenever a change in Lift webapp is made, I need to request maven to recompile/retest the whole webapp (which is a really heavy overhead).

I wonder if there is something like realtime compilation (and test) tools that can be used for Lift?

Comment: Programming on Lift on Realtime, is not the best title. Realtime have a connotation of real-time programming (the correctness of the calculation depends also on how long it took).

Answer (score 9):

SBT (aka "[simple-build-tool](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/)") has a mode where the it will monitor the project's files and directories for updates, and will re-run the build and test of your project.  This works by adding a tilde in front of the target:

```
$ sbt ~test
```

I don't know how to get Maven to do this.  For what it's worth, SBT uses Ivy for dependency management, and is itself Maven-friendly.

Comment: How ~test can be used in accordance with jetty

Answer (score 7):

I'd simply use the `scala:cc` target and JRebel.

Answer (score 0):

If you make maven work in online mode, it will always try to update or download missed plugins or POM which is not necessary. So when I already have the necessary dependencies, I make maven work in offline mode by appending "-o" in the maven command. That will save a lot of time, hope it helps.